# Load files with two indexes in one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to load 28 files with the same amount of rows and columns so it wont iterate index through all files data 0-2911, but only one file data with index 0-103 and give a second index 1-28 for every new file data started?

Here is the code that I wrote that iterates through all data:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r"C:/Users/Measurment_Data/Test_1"
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.dat")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\t", names=["Voltage", "Current"], header=None) 
    li.append(df)
    
frame = pd.concat(li, axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
frame
```

Output:

```
ID  Voltage Current
0   NaN 1.000000e+00
1   0.00    -3.047149e-06
2   0.04    -4.941096e-06
3   0.08    -4.472754e-06
4   0.12    -1.053477e-05
... ... ...
2907    -0.16   1.194359e-06
2908    -0.12   5.489425e-06
2909    -0.08   -9.656614e-09
2910    -0.04   -3.427169e-06
2911    -0.00   -2.173696e-06
```

I would like to have new indexes for every new loaded file. Something like this:

```
File ID  Curr    Volt
1   0   0.00    1.00E+00
1   1   0.00    -3.05E-06
1   2   0.04    -4.94E-06
...
1   102   0.08    -4.47E-06
1   103   0.12    -1.05E-05
...
2   0   0.00    2.00E+00
2   1   4.00    -3.05E-06
2   2   0.44    -3.94E-06
...
2   102   5.08    -6.47E-06
2   103   0.22    -6.05E-05
...
...
27   0   0.00    2.00E+00
27   1   4.00    -3.05E-06
27   2   0.44    -3.94E-06
...
27   102   5.08    -6.47E-06
27   103   0.22    -6.05E-05
...
28   0   0.00    2.00E+00
28   1   4.00    -3.05E-06
28   2   0.44    -3.94E-06
...
28   102   5.08    -6.47E-06
28   103   0.22    -6.05E-05
```

I would like to easily access the values of every file with index, so for example all values from 0-5 from 28 files.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a new column after you read every file, then concatenate using default value of `ignore_index`:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r"C:/Users/Measurment_Data/Test_1"
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.dat")

li = []
j = 1
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\t", names=["Voltage", "Current"], header=None) 
    df.insert(0, 'File', '')
    df["File"] = j
    j += 1
    li.append(df)
    
frame = pd.concat(li, axis = 0)
frame
```

Give it a try!

Comment: I would like to easily access the values of every file with index, so for example all values from 0-5 from 28 files so it doesn't fix my problem, as I still have index from 0-2911

Comment: Doesn't each files contains indexes 0-103 when you read it? Try adding another column with a `range()` for each file. Without looking at the file can't help you